# Monogoid database Setup in Mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Mongodb and Mongoid as mapper. For example in Active-record we used rake db:migrate to migrating and creating database . What is the command for monogoid so that the collections declare in model gets created in local mongo database.

Comment: There's no schema in MongoDB -- and collections are normally created on demand when using MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is a NoSQL database which has no schema (documents within same collection can differ in terms of contents). So you don't need to do a database migration when you change the contents or add new field or remove existing fields in your ODM. Even you don't need to run db:migrate task to create a collection. It get created on your request. It is as simple as serializing your data into a binary file (BSON).